# S3 bucket policy to list multiple objects in public bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I have set up a public bucket in S3 and copied multiple objects into it. In this case they are jpeg photos.

I want to share all these objects with anonymous public users (friends), but I want to send them one static website address for the bucket and for the objects to show up as a list (or at least show all the images) when they click on that one address link.

Is this possible to display the objects this way using S3 to public users who don't have an S3 account?

The alternative I know of is to send them a unique link to each of the objects in the bucket (which would take forever!).

Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

S3 doesn't have anything built-in to do a "directory index" like nginx and Apache can do. It can be done with [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/lambda/), though.

[I built a rudimentary image index with lambda](https://github.com/tedder/lambda-functions/), you might be able to adapt it to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

yes. 
you can host an static webpage inside a s3 bucket: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

just generate a static html page with links to all the photos, upload it in the bucket, set the bucket to serve as a static webpage and give the link to it.

Or, for the extra lazy :) https://github.com/rgrp/s3-bucket-listing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, they helped me to find a really simple solution. On a different forum I found someone has written some script and put it in a link that you just upload straight into your bucket and that puts all the objects into a simple list...... genius!

This is the link:

http://regexp.s3.amazonaws.com/list.html

So for the less techy people (like me) you literally upload that link above into your bucket. Even if you haven't downloaded it onto your PC, just copy and paste it into the upload file path.

When I uploaded it, the file appeared in the S3 bucket as list.html

Make sure the file is readable and you've set the ACL appropriately. And make sure your bucket has a policy that allows anyone to access it.

Your bucket objects(content) are then shown at the url link below.

```
http://<your bucket name>.s3.amazonaws.com/list.html
```

Where `<your bucket name>` is written above, replace that part with just the name of your bucket.

And you should be able to click on that link and see the list of objects in your bucket. Once you get your head around it, it is actually very simple.